# Cosmetic fix for installing decking board when not parallel to house?

Tags: framing, deck, measuring

I am expanding the deck that goes very far (35 x 48 feet ~ 1000 sqft). So I am pretty sure the further end will not perfectly parallel to the house. It could be 1-2 inch off from one end to the other end.

Imagine a scenario like this:

[image]

If I start to install the composite decking starting from the house, the one near the last board will end up like the red rectangle in the photo. So should I cut the last board in a weird way (one end is shorter than the other end)?

It's composite decking board so I cannot "play" with the gaps by having larger gaps or something like that. So I came up with few options:

**Option 1:**

I am thinking about doing the "picture frame" method around the edges by installing #1 and #2. Then at the end, I will install #3 (as photo below). But then I am wondering how many inches a composite decking board and "hangover" the edge of the trim joists?

[image]

**Option 2:**

Without using picture frame method, I would start installing the boards from the further end of the house. This will result in the odd looking board near the house right at the foot step. I am assuming it's "harder" to see the imperfection this way?

What would be the best cosmetic way to manage situation like this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Look like I found my own answer here: trex.com/trex/groups/content/documents/document/trex_004114.pdf as basically you could have 2.5 overhang and you can screw from bottom up at 45 degree angle. Interesting! If you the deck is totally not parallel and has more than 3 inches offset. I imagine the easy way to fix would be to "double" the trim joists with another joist that has spacer at one end?